Can I combine Cunning Strike: Withdraw & Cunning Action: Dash?
Cunning Strike allows Withdraw:

Immediately after the [sneak] attack, you move up to half your Speed without provoking Opportunity attacks.

So, with Speed of 30, could I do the following:

Move in, say, 15 ft to the target.
Attack + Sneak Attack (if I have adv., at least)
Use Cunning Strike to Withdraw, moving 15 ft away without provoking OA
Use Cunning Action to Dash another 30 ft away, not provoking OA because I'm already beyond 5 ft

Additionally, if I was already close to the target, same idea:

Attack + Sneak Attack (assuming I have adv)
Cunning Strike: Withdraw 15 ft
Cunning Action: Dash 30 ft away

Basically I guess I don't know if I can move and then use Cunning Strike to Withdraw. Technically, I'd imagine that as long as I have at least 5 ft of movement left, I can withdraw without provoking an OA — it's just that, once I employ Cunning Strike to withdraw, the rest of my "Move" action is cut down to 15 ft. (?)

Just to clarify the terminology: "Move" is not an action. It's just your movement, which is a seperate thing, as you don't need an action to move.

Maybe obvious, but: Unlike Disengage, which prevents AoO for the rest of your turn, Cunning Strike Withdraw prevents them only for that distance of 0.5 * speed. If you need to move past other hostiles with your other 2 * speed, they could still AoO.

Do you think my answer, answers your question sufficiently, as that it might be accepted?

Yes! Sorry, this was a really great response! :)

Yes, you can use both on the same turn
Cunning Strike Withdraw works without using any additional action of any sort. You just forgo a Sneak Attack die and can then freely move up to have your speed, after attacking. Cunning Action uses your Bonus Action, which you haven't used at that time and can thus use to Dash with this feature.
This Cunning Strike option also does not consume your regular movement, it just enables you to move those 15 feet in addition to any other movement you have for that turn. Meaning you can actually move even further that you thought, as you could:

Move up to 30 feet towards your opponent
Attack with Sneak Attack, forgoing 1 die (assuming its conditions are met)
Withdraw up to 15 feet without Attacks of Opportunity or using up your regular movement
If you have any movement remaining from Step 1, move it
Dash another 30 feet in any direction with Cunning Action

In the case of you already being next to the target at the start of your turn, you could:

Sneak attack
Withdraw for 15 feet
Move 30 feet with your regular movement
Cunning Action Dash for 30 more feet or use your Bonus Action for something else entirely

